# Probability: independent standard normal random variable

Tags: probability

Given $x_1, x_2, x_3, x_4, x_5$ be independent standard normal random variable and $\bar x$ the sample mean $\bar x= (x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 + x_5)/5$. Then $\Pr(\bar x\leqslant c)$

What is c?

I tried to rewrite the given information mean which is $\bar x=∑_{x\in\{1,2,3,4,5\}}x_i/5 $ and $x_i\sim\mathcal N(0,1)$ then got stuck. What to do next?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out linear combination of independent normal variables.

In this case $\bar x = N(0, \frac{1}{5})$
Now you can use:

$P(\bar x \le c) = P(\frac{\bar x - 0}{\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}} \le \frac{c - 0}{\frac{1}{\sqrt 5}}) = P(z \le c\sqrt 5)$

Comment: How can I find the c in this corresponding equation?

Comment: You need the probability to find c or given c we can find probability. Right now we have neither.

Answer (score 0):

The sum of two normally distributed random variables is a normally distributed random variable, whose mean is the sum of their means, and whose variance is the sum of their variance.

By induction therefore, the sum of five standard normally distributed random variables is ....